# What's the [status] of my burnination request?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Yes, there is actually a [status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status) tag.

> a summary of the current state of a process, an application, a function or an object, or a response code about the execution of a request or a function (i.e. return code, or error code). For status bar use the tag statusbar. For http-status

(Yes, it does actually trail off in the middle of a sentence like that).

The summary goes on to state that:

> A status is a summary of the current state of a process, an application, a function or an object. It can also be a response code related to the execution of a request or a function, typically a return code, or an error code.

This kind of speaks for itself - that's 7 possible uses for this tag, and I can think of several more. This tag is so ambiguous that it's of little use to the site. Can we burninate it?

Comment: [status-review] for 6-8

Comment: As long as they aren_'t missued tags should stay, so my vote would be against burninate

Comment: @nvm What's the proper use of this, though?